# Calculations with specific positions within a matrix

Tags: matrix, vector, fortran, fortran77

I've written a code that reads and prints a set of streamflow values in the format I need.

Basically all data is stored in a matrix with 1020 lines and 320 columns. It can be a smaller matrix, i.e., if I don't have so many streamflow values, but it'll never be larger than that.

Every line is a specific month in a specific year. Line 1 is Jan.1931 and line 1020 is Dec.2015 and every columns, from the 1st to the 320th, represents a gauging station (GS).

I need now to calculate the average value for the same month throughout the whole time series for every GS. To clear any doubts about this previous statement I will give you an example.

I need the average streamflow value for the month of January for GS #1 throughout my timeline, so I need to sum Jan.1931 + Jan.1932 + Jan.1933+...+Jan.2015 and then divide by the number of years, in this case, (2015-1931+1)=85 years. All this for the same GS, in this case, #1.

I cannot mix GSs so the code must repeat this operation for every GS, and obviously, for every month. In the end, I'll have the average streamflow value for every month from 1931 to 2015 for every GS.

Here's what I thought. I can store this as a column vector and store streamflow values for the same GS in rows; so I'd have a (12x1) vector in which every line is a streamflow value, being line 1 the average streamflow value for Jan. and line 12 the  the average streamflow value for Dec. However, this has to be done for every GS, therefore, I'd have 320 column vectors (12x1) by the end of it. It'd look like this for GS1, for instance.

```
avgGS1 : avgJan
         avgFeb
         avgMar
          ...
         avgDec
```

Then I thought I could also store this information in line vectors of dimension equal to (1x320). In this case, I'd have a vector that would store all the average streamflow values for Jan, another one for Feb., another for March until the last one for December.

Knowing that my matrix from which data is read is displayed sort of like this:

```
             GS1   GS2   GS3   GS4   G5 ... G320
Jan.1931
Feb.1931
Marc.1931
...
Jan.1932
Feb.1932
...
Dec.2015
```

I'd store my 12 vectors like this:

```
             GS1    GS2    GS3  ... GS320
avg.Jan     ( a      b      c   ...  n )
avg.Feb     ( d      e      f   .... m)
...
avg.Dec     (g       h      i  ...   o)
```

The problem is that I can't think of a way to do it automatically. The closest I got to any doing any code for this was:

```
real*4    i, q(1020,320), sumqjan(320), avgqjan 

i=0
sumqjan=0
do i=1,1020, 12
   sumqjan = sumqjan + (q(i,gsnumber), gsnumber=1,320)
enddo 

avgqjan= sumqjan/(numbofyears)
```

i is a variable to goes from the first line to the last line, sumqjan is the sum of all streamflow values - here called q- for January and the avgqjan is the vector containing the 320 average Q values for every single GS. In my do-loop, I have an increment of 12. This is because if I know the first line is Jan, if I add 12 to it, I'll always end up with another January streamflow value.

I followed by

```
i=0
sumqfev=0
do i=2,1020, 12
   sumqfeb = sumqfeb + (q(i,gsnumber), gsnumber=1,320)
enddo 

avgqfeb= sumqfeb/(numbofyears)
```

In this example above, I am performing the same calculations I did for January, however, my i variable starts at 2. If I know my second line is Feb, every line I'll get from this one will be Feb. as long as I keep adding 12 in do-loop.

I repeat this process for every month but it doesn't look ideal. I'm looking for ways to perform these calculations and store these values faster.

I'd post my code here but it's not of my sole authorship, therefore, I can't share it in its plenitude.

If you know a solution or have an idea that might work,please, go ahead and share it. I appreciate the help! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I will break it down to a simpler, applicable problem.  The below program computes the average for a 1D array.  It uses count and a logical mask to exclude numbers that are zero (if this is ok for you).  Therefore this is the average of only the nonzero components of the array, which I think is what you are after.

To upgrade my simplistic answer to your problem consider using array slices.  Using those you can select only the portions of your array that you are interested in.

```
program average

integer :: array(10) = 0

do i = 1,5
  array(i) = 3
end do

write (*,*) 'count   ', count(array /= 0)
write (*,*) 'sum     ', sum(array)
write (*,*) 'average ', sum(array)/count(array /= 0)

end program
```

Output:

```
 count              5
 sum               15
 average            3
```

Array slice pseudocode:

```
array(row_start:row_end:interval, column_start:column_end:interval)
```

I'm not sure if I fully answered your question but I hope I offered some food for thought.

Comment: thanks a lot for your contribution! I'll make the best out of it,